# Web page is blank (Problem with react-router)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, mern

I am trying to learn MERN mainly react by following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CqJlxBYj-M) and I have followed the code exactly but when I run the server and open the web page it is blank.
I know the problem is with the four React route paths because if I remove them the web page displays the navbar. I also get no errors when running the server.
this is the app.js file code:

```
import React from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,} from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercise from "./components/edit-exercise.component";
import CreateExercise from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <br/>
      <Route path="/" exact component={ExercisesList} />
      <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise} />
      <Route path="/create" component={CreateExercise} />
      <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the code for create-exercise:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class CreateExercise extends Component{

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>You are on the create exercises List componentt</p>
            </div>
          
        )
    }
}
```

The other three have the same code.
This is the link to the github containing the tutorial's code:
https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa3VfM2thaXc4b1RoODUxWkh0MXprN2NFV3E2QXxBQ3Jtc0trbTdTQll1WmVFQ1hRb0ZOVWlUVVROUG1ta2RranJocVFmektvb0F0VWpKQjNWY0tIelBuZ1ZLNDU5VVFhSVZiS3VGTnJHT19ja0NYdVI3OFdkZVVQS0ZoLV8wQkxhT2xqeS0yakNPSXNyZjlLTW5Vbw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fbeaucarnes%2Fmern-exercise-tracker-mongodb

Comment: No errors on server but what about in browser developer tools console (F12)?

Comment: Which react-router version are you using, if v6 then use element instead of component.

Comment: my react-router-dom version is 6.2.1 Should I switch component with element?

Answer (score 0):

In React-Router version 6 you need to use element

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#add-some-routes

Example:

```
<Route path="/" element={<App />} />
<Route path="expenses" element={<Expenses />} />
<Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />} />
```

Comment: I made this change                                                                                                                                    <Route path="/" exact element={<ExercisesList />}>
 <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditExercise />} />
 <Route path="/create" element={<CreateExercise />} />
 <Route path="/user" element={<CreateUser />} />   Though nothing changed still a blank page when I run it